# What minimum energy is required to create tracks in a cloud chamber?

Tags: radiation

What is the minimum ionizing radiation required for that? I am currently living in Fukushima prefecture and I was wondering if let`s say a flower from my yard that emits 1 pSv will create visible tracks? My dosimeter only shows Sieverts so I cannot be very specific. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to do precision radiation measurements, a cloud chamber is not the way to go. You can buy precisely calibrated electronic instruments for that job which are far more sensitive than other physical detectors, if you really want to. Their design is not a home project, though, and they are very expensive. In general any attempt at "home dosimetry" is going to create a lot of poor data. Radiation measurement at this level is hard and you have to take the jump and trust the people who do this for a living.

Comment: I completely agree with @CuriousOne. IMO, the (home built) cloud chamber will not solve anything. I would expect a major contribution from beta decays followed by gamma deexcitation. Alphas (if any) will not penetrate to you chamber. Electrons are difficult, it would be interesting to see the tracks from a radioactive source placed just by side of a chamber. As your activity is probably very small and competing with the background, the viable method is HPGe detector, that clearly distinguishes gammas from different isotopes and background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cloud chamber will show individual cosmic rays and individual alpha and beta particle tracks.

An alpha particle may have say 5 MeV of energy, which is $8 \times 10^{-13}$ J

The Sv unit is the biological effect of $1$ Joule of radiation on $1$ kg of matter. So a pSv is the biological effect of $1 \times 10^{-12}$ J on $1$ kg....

so my answer to your question is yes - but the [Sievert scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert) is pretty complicated and beware that a cloud chamber won't observe gamma radiation nearly as efficiently as alpha and beta particles because most gammas will pass straight through, whereas every alpha will leave a clear track. As pointed out by dmckee gammas can be observed if they, for example, Compton scatter or produce an electron positron pair.

Finally, I should say that given where you are living I can give no guarantee about this - but if I were living where you are I would probably build myself a cloud chamber as you plan to. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: *"beware that a cloud chamber won't observe gamma radiation."* Well, unless the photon Compton scatters or pair produces (or does both repeatedly resulting in a shower).

Comment: Honestly, if somebody wanted to do precision dosimetry, they would simply buy a gamma spectrometer with absolute calibration. Admittedly, that's typically a very expensive instrument.

Comment: @dmckee - yes sorry my point is that gamma is so much less efficient... in the low density gas cloud chamber than say alpha detection and so as far a sievert scale goes (re: human damage due to radiation) the cloud chamber won't be nearly as sensitive in Sieverts to gammas - I will edit, thanks for the comment - I learn so much here :-)

Comment: Sorry, yom. That wasn't meant to be a criticism, but a minor clarification of a good enough answer that I didn't need to add a separate response.

Comment: @dmckee - no problem, thanks for the comment I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

This is to be read together with the checked answer. There are easy cloud chambers to be home made, [like this one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=400xfGmSlqQ)

It is easy to make, and the reason you should watch it is to realize that in a cloud chamber there will always be muon tracks ionizing the air vapor mix and creating seeds for a track. You will need a type of anti-coincidence to make sure that any tracks you see come from particles of your flowers:

1) in a basement under meters of cement the muons are less

2) mu metal is a good shield for muons, but that means a lab

3) You could get a statistical effect by taking two measurements, flowers in  the cup, flowers off and count the tracks in both cases for the same length of time.

"In the cup" because  a plastic cup could have  a wall of [0.2mm thickness](http://smallb.sidbi.in/sites/default/files/knowledge_base/disposable_plastic_cup.pdf) and alpha's would be absorbed [there](http://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k16940&pageid=icb.page102829&pageContentId=icb.pagecontent270778&view=view.do&viewParam_name=indepth.html) and not enter the chamber. The flower will shrivel from the ice but this will not affect the nuclear properties of its constituents. ( thanks to jaromrax pointing this out in  a comment)

P.S.

I just realized because the alpha range is [3 cm in air](http://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k16940&pageid=icb.page102829&pageContentId=icb.pagecontent270778&view=view.do&viewParam_name=indepth.html), the radiation from the flower will be clearly seen and not confused with most cosmic muons, it should be centered around the flower for 3 cm.

Comment: I love it how you are basically describing an experimental setup that will take a full time grad student a couple of years to perfect... meters of concrete shielding... anti-coincidence detector and trigger... control measurements. Maybe we could try to find an unused mine for actually effective shielding against cosmic rays? :-) Seriously... this is hard stuff and you know it.

Comment: @CuriousOne  you might be surprised at how many basements exist, there are locations where there are two basements. I am not asking for anticoincidence , but for the use of logic. I just want to draw attention that a cloud chamber will show tracks anyway, Fukishima or not. It seems to me you fast read my posts and fill in the blanks your create.

Comment: @annav - I just remind, usual alphas (5-6 MeV) will not penetrate even 50um of mylar. The sample should be inside the chamber, if this is possible for other reasons...

Comment: @jaromrax , thanks, I was too lazy to check. will do now

Comment: @annav - If they won't penetrate 50um of mylar, how much air will they penetrate?

Comment: @mmesser314  3 cm according to the link I gave

Comment: @mmesser314 thats 3cm in air at 1 atm. --- annna v thanks for your useful post - love the linked video - will have to try that